# Getting “Invalid argument” error when attempting to check PNG images with pngcheck

Tags: png

I've learned about [`pngcheck`](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html) which I was hoping to use to find and highlight possible corrupted png files.

When I run the command `c:\pngcheck\pngcheck *.png` in the folder containing the files, I get

```
*.png: Invalid argument
ERROR: *.png
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: My first guess is that pngcheck expects a path to a file, not a pattern.  If you have several files to check you may need to use your shell to expand the pattern and run pngcheck on each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pngcheck` does not support wildcards in Windows. You will need to loop it to run on each file. CD to your image directory and you can run this. Replace the path to where your `pngcheck.win64.exe` is. You can also replace the `*.png` with a full directory if you wish to not CD to the image directory. I.e. `(c:\images\*.png)`

```
for /r %i in (*.png) do "c:\pngcheck-3.0.3-win32\pngcheck.win64.exe" "%i"
```

If you run only `"c:\pngcheck-3.0.3-win32\pngcheck.win64.exe"`, you can see all the flags.

```
Options:
   -7  print contents of tEXt chunks, escape chars >=128 (for 7-bit terminals)
   -c  colorize output (for ANSI terminals)
   -p  print contents of PLTE, tRNS, hIST, sPLT and PPLT (can be used with -q)
   -q  test quietly (output only errors)
   -s  search for PNGs within another file
   -t  print contents of tEXt chunks (can be used with -q)
   -v  test verbosely (print most chunk data)
   -vv test very verbosely (decode & print line filters)
   -w  suppress windowBits test (a more-stringent compression check)
   -x  search for PNGs within another file and extract them when found
```

To address the comment below about running the command and writing only the errors to a file you can use the `-q` flag and append data to a file with `>> errors.txt`

```
for /r %i in (*.png) do "c:\pngcheck-3.0.3-win32\pngcheck.win64.exe" -q "%i" >> errors.txt
```

Comment: I think `pngcheck` does not support wildcards *at all*. In Unix/Linux `pngcheck *.png` works because *the shell* expands `*.png` before it starts `pngcheck`. The program gets the result of the expansion as an array of arguments. AFAIK in Windows a program gets its arguments as one *string* and it's a responsibility of the program to expand wildcards, split to words, remove quotes etc. The program may or may not use some standard function for this. It seems whatever `pngcheck` uses in Windows does not support wildcards indeed. My point is in Linux wildcards work without support from `pngcheck`.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks.  Running for /r %i in (*.png) do "c:\pngcheck-3.0.3-win32\pngcheck.win64.exe" "%i" works, but is there a way to create a logfile listing files which has errorred?  I think it's >checkdata.txt, but unsure how to add into the command line.

Comment: @TenneR yes, you can use `-q` flag and append to file with `>> errors.txt`. Please see edit.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help @Narzard ... your suggestion worked a treat!